# Formatting the date in unix to include suffix on day (st, nd, rd and th)

Tags: regex, unix, date, textmate

How can I add the suffix on the *day* number of a unix date?

I'll explain. I have a TextMate bundle snippit that writes out today's date. It uses unix date and formatting. Here is the code:

```
`date +%A` `date +%d` `date +%B` `date +%Y`
```

It outputs:

**Monday 22 March 2010**

I would like to add the suffix to the *day* (**st**, **nd**, **rd** and **th**) like so:

**Monday 22nd March 2010**

As far as I can see, there is no native function in the unix date formatting, like there is in PHP (j). How would I achieve this in unix? A complicated regex on the day number?

Comment: Not actually answering your question, but I'd consolidate the date commands:

date "+%A %d %B %Y"-> Monday 22 March 2010

Comment: If I were you, I'd write a small PHP script (since you already know how to do it there), and execute it. I don't know, if it's possible to install PHP on the target system though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have something similar working on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 8.10). I don't think it will work with Solaris, the one machine I tested did not allow using a _ character following the % to avoid padding the field with a 0. The non-padding allows date to return 1 instead of 01 (01st doesn't look right versus 1st).

I use a shell function (again, your OS or shell version may not like the way I defined the function) named DaySuffix, then call that func as part of the date call. The func itself is fairly hacky, I'm sure there is a better way to do this but it works for me.  Note the special cases for 11, 12, & 13 - you've got to love the English language!

```
#!/bin/sh

DaySuffix() {
    if [ "x`date +%-d | cut -c2`x" = "xx" ]
    then
        DayNum=`date +%-d`
    else
        DayNum=`date +%-d | cut -c2`
    fi

    CheckSpecialCase=`date +%-d`
    case $DayNum in
    0 )
      echo "th" ;;
    1 )
      if [ "$CheckSpecialCase" = "11" ]
      then
        echo "th"
      else
        echo "st"
      fi ;;
    2 )
      if [ "$CheckSpecialCase" = "12" ]
      then
        echo "th"
      else
        echo "nd"
      fi ;;
    3 )
      if [ "$CheckSpecialCase" = "13" ]
      then
        echo "th"
      else
        echo "rd"
      fi ;;
    [4-9] )
      echo "th" ;;
    * )
      return 1 ;;
    esac
}

# Using consolidated date command from chris_l
# Also using %-d instead of %d so it doesn't pad with 0's
date "+%A %-d`DaySuffix` %B %Y"
```

Comment: I was able to use this code to fix my problem. However, I could not use +%-d because the dash is not allowed. Only strict unix formatting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_(Unix). I used +%e in it's place and it works well. Although I think it adds an extra space with single digits (like 1-9). I'll fix that problem on the 1st April. Thanks for the help. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Try.

```
#!/bin/sh
DaySuffix() {
  case `date +%d` in
    1|21|31) echo "st";;
    2|22)    echo "nd";;
    3|23)    echo "rd";;
    *)       echo "th";;
  esac
}
date "+%A %d`DaySuffix` %B %Y"
```

Comment: `date +%-d` might match better to prevent buffering with leading 0's.

Comment: I had to change the script to include leading zeros, e.g., `01|21|31) echo "st";;` (I'm on macOS).

Comment: @robenkleene, on macOS I used `date +%e` to avoid the zero-padding altogether.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/ksh
DateSuffix() {
if [ "$1" -eq "1" ] || [ "$1" -eq "21" ] || [ "$1" -eq "31" ]
then
echo 'st'
elif [ "$1" -eq "2" ] || [ "$1" -eq "22" ]
then
echo 'nd'
elif [ "$1" -eq "3" ] [ "$1" -eq "23" ]
then
echo 'rd'
else
echo 'th'
fi   
}
date "+%A %d`DateSuffix` %B %Y"
```