# date bash command to get day number with st, nd, th suffix

Tags: bash, date, datetime

I'm trying to use the `date` bash command to get a string like this:

```
(May 30th, 2022)
```

I'm getting close with `date +"(%B %-d, %Y)"`, which prints string like that:

```
(May 30, 2022)
```

However, the `th` suffix is missing.

Which format string should I use with `date` to get the `st`, `nd` or `th` suffix, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495459/formatting-the-date-in-unix-to-include-suffix-on-day-st-nd-rd-and-th

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
date +"(%B %-d, %Y)" | sed 's/1,/1st,/;s/2,/2nd,/;s/3,/3rd,/;s/\([0-9]\),/\1th,/'
```

Comment: You can easily combine these `sed` scripts into one; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands